# Identify the PID of process which is transmitting icmp packets

Tags: python, linux, networking, process, packets

I have written a program which will create and transmit the icmp packets over the network.

Now, I want to write a program which will identity the processes (PID) in the system which are transmitting the icmp packets.
If I am not wrong, possible output of these program will be PID of the previous program that I have coded and some system processes which are
creating and transmitting icmp packets.

NOTE : I have used python for coding, scapy for packets manipulation and PySide for GUI(extra information)
I am running this program in Fedora 20 in VMWare.

Comment: It might be possible to glean all the info you want from /proc, but if you wrote the program sending the ICMP packets, it would be FAR easier to have the ICMP sending program drop a run a file in /var/run or the like that contains its PID.  Your second program can read the PID from this file. If they are co-dependent, the first can spawn the second, passing it its own PID.

Comment: @tMC: Can you explain how /var/run directory works? And another question, in /proc directory, is it possible to find if the process is sending an ICMP packet or not?

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote the first program, it would far easier to just have it write its own PID to a run file you can consume in the second program.  Something like this:

First program:

```
open('/var/run/program.pid', 'w').write(str(os.getpid()))
```

In the second program:

```
pid = int(open('/var/run/program.pid', 'r').read())
```

You'll need to add appreciate error handling etc; but that is the basic idea.

Comment: That might be the solution but another question what if i dont know the PID of 1st program? I mean i dont know whether the 1st program is running or not, and 2nd program is continuously checking for process that sends ICMP packet. How will you solve then?

Comment: The first program 'knows' its own pid (via the `getpid` function) which it writes to the run file.  if you want to ensure that the first program is running via the second, you can verify the pid file exists and that the process identified by the pid you read from that file is the process you expect.  This is easily done via the `/proc/<pid>` directory.

Comment: Let me explain you the complete scenario. This question is a small part in my security project. 1st program is an attacker program which is sending icmp packet. 2nd program is a detection program which identify the process which is creating and transmitting packets. So, naturally, 1st program i.e. attacker program will not reveled its pid.